# Generalising Applicative and Monad to more categories

Tags: haskell, category-theory

In Haskell, we've got the functions:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
(=<<) :: Monad f => (a -> f b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

I can write `fmap` in terms of `pure` and `(<*>)` like so:

```
fmap x = (<*>) (pure x)
```

I can also write `(<*>)` in terms of `(=<<)` and `pure` like so:

```
m1 <*> m2 = (\x -> (\y -> pure (x y)) =<< m2) =<< m1
```

Noticed earlier I flipped the bind operator from it's usual `(>>=)` to `(=<<)`. The reason I did this is because I now want to generalise the functions like so:

```
fmap :: (Functor f, Category cat) => cat a b -> cat (f a) (f b)
pure :: (Applicative f, Category cat) => a -> f a
(<*>) :: (Applicative f, Category cat) => f (cat a b) -> cat (f a) (f b)
(=<<) :: (Monad f, Category cat) => cat a (f b) -> cat (f a) (f b)
```

Interestingly, I can still write `fmap` in terms of `pure` and `(<*>)` exactly the same as before:

```
fmap x = (<*>) (pure x)
```

However, I work out how can't write `(<*>)` in terms of `pure` and `(=<<)`. Is it possible? I suspect it isn't, but I also suspect it's possible to write `(<*>)` in terms of `pure` and `(=<<)` for more categories other than ordinary functions. I also suspect to do this my category needs a few extra functions.

So I'm guessing perhaps I need a class and a few instances, like so:

```
class Category cat => SpecialCategory cat where
  ...

instance SpecialCategory (->) where
  ...

instance SpecialCategory SomeOtherCategory where
  ...
```

With this approach I should be able to define any special characteristics a category needs to be able to define `(<*>)` in terms of `(=<<)` and `pure`.

What are those characteristics? Or am I completely off track in my approach to making this generalisation?

Comment: Somewhat trivially, `Arrow cat` is enough for this since you can project any function into an `Arrow`. :)

Comment: I think that's the insight I needed Alec, thanks!

Comment: Actually @Alec, still even with making Category an Arrow I still can't get it to fit, but I may be missing something.

Comment: I think you're trying to generalise the wrong thing. You certainly can't map a `Functor` (an endofunctor on **Hask**) over an arbitrary category. In general functors can go between different categories, so I'd start by modelling that (`class (Category d, Category c) => CFunctor d c f | f -> d c where cmap :: d a b -> c (f a) (f b)`). Monads are always endofunctors, though (`class CFunctor c c m => CMonad c m | m -> c where { creturn :: c a (m a); cjoin :: c (m (m a)) -> c (m a) }`). And have a read of https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/02/06/applicative-functors/

Comment: You might want to look at [cartesian closed categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category), lambda calculus's main squeeze.